Asyncio's run_coroutine_threadsafe is not running coroutines while my main event loop is run_forever() in telethon
I am using telethon, on some code, i am inside a synchronus(def) function and i need to call and return the result of telethon client's asynchronus methods using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe.
But its not returning the result of the coroutine telethon's method instead it get stucked.
I used nest_asyncio module which solves this and can use run_until_complete, but I do not want to use nest_asyncio.
I want to know, is there any other way to run coroutines and must return the result inside def function while my main event loop is running forever?
I tried call_soon_threadsafe call_soon call_later run_in_executor but i do not know their usage & am confused!

i fixed this issue later, thanks
